# ServiceMix and Windows Service

Tags: apache-servicemix

I have created Servicemix as windows service using wrapper but how to start and stop bundle while service is running? or any other way to start and stop the bundle

Comment: Can you explain better what you mean by starting and stopping bundle and what you really want to do? The service wrapper is only for starting ServiceMix itself, not for doing 'extra work' and starter individual applications or whatnot.

Comment: Thank You, Yes I got to know service wrapper is for starting the servicemix but i need a way to start particular feature or bundle deployed inside servicemix, while the servicemix is started using wrapper.

Comment: Then install those bundles from servicemix so they are pre-installed, or you can add them to the boot feature list in the servicemix configuration file

Comment: So if in case i have to start any bundle which is in resolved state, i have to stop the windows service and then start servicemix manually and start the bundle. Am i right ?

Comment: My question now is if any bundle is in resolved state is it possible to start when servicemix is started as windows service?

Comment: I suggest to try it out instead of asking all the time

Comment: I tried with one but no option for question